# MySQL connection with Python is not working

Tags: python, mysql, database-connection

I want to connect with MySQL through Python, although I am successful in connecting using directly writing the credentials like user name, passwd, etc, but I want to make it a little dynamic. So I tried:

```
import mysql.connector
import pandas as pd

def connection():
  host=input('Enter host')
  user=input('Enter User Name')
  passwd=int(input('passwd'))
  database=input('database')
  mydb= mysql.connector.connect(host="host", user="user", passwd="passwd", database="database")
return mydb
  connection()
```

However, it gives error in the end:

InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'host:3306' (11001 getaddrinfo failed)

Please help me out. And if you have better solution while bringing some dynamic user input credential, I will be really grateful. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried this?   mydb= mysql.connector.connect(host=host, user=user, passwd=passwd, database=database)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the connect method of the mysql.connector you are hardcoding the values when you pass them as strings.

Use `mysql.connector.connect(host=host, user=user, passwd=passwd, database=database)` instead.

You're also parsing the password to a int, I don't think mysql will like that, just use it as a string.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing stirng like "host" to the database and not the variables

So remove the double quotes like

```
import mysql.connector
import pandas as pd

def connection():
  host=input('Enter host')
  user=input('Enter User Name')
  passwd=int(input('passwd'))
  database=input('database')
  mydb= mysql.connector.connect(host=host, user=user, passwd=passwd, database=database)
return mydb
  connection()
```